# $.map object properties to a new array with similar names

Tags: jquery

I have the following array of objects:

```
var blah = [
    { foo: 1, bar: 2 },
    { foo: 2, bar: 1 }
];
```

I would like to change the property names from `foo` to `Foo` and `bar` to `Bar`. So I gave `jQuery.map` a try. However, I'm not sure what to return:

```
var newBlah = $.map(blah, function(i, v){
    return /* ...? */;
});
```

Desired result:

```
console.log(newBlah); //[{ Foo: 1, Bar: 2... etc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the names are known, it'd be easier to just use an object literal:

```
return { Foo: v.foo, Bar: v.bar };
```

If you want to capitalize the property names of any object in general, it's a little more involved:

```
var result = {};

for(var x in v) {
    if(v.hasOwnProperty(x)) {
        result[x.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + x.substring(1)] = v[x];
    }
}

return result;
```

(Although that doesn't work properly with getters and setters and such.)

P.S. Your arguments are in the wrong order; `jQuery.map` is `v, i`, whereas `jQuery.fn.map` is `i, v`.

Comment: Yea, mixed up the argument order with `$.each` :) `hasOwnProperty` doesn't work in IE, right? The `ìn` operator would be working across all browsers AFAIK

Comment: @Johan: It would, but the `in` operator looks up the prototype chain and so would always be `true`! `hasOwnProperty` has worked in IE since version 8, I *think*. (Finding compatibility info now.)

Comment: @Johan: Aha, I remember using it in IE7. `hasOwnProperty` was introduced in IE6 but isn't defined on host objects (e.g. DOM nodes) until IE9.

Answer (score 3):

You create a new object with the values from the old object:

```
var newBlah = $.map(blah, function(v, i){
  return { Foo: v.foo, Bar: v.bar };
});
```

Note: The parameters in the callback is the item, then the index.

Comment: I actually tried this, but I swapped places with `v` and `i`. So thanks for explaining that :). Mixed it up with index and values in `$.each`

Answer (score 2):

```
var newBlah = $.map(blah, function(i, v){
    return {
        Foo : this.foo,
        Bar : this.bar
    }
});
```

if you want to make it generic, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

The following approach would also work. It copies the property value, then deletes an unnecessary property.

```
var blah = [{foo:1, bar:2}, {foo:2, bar:3}];
for (var i = 0; i < blah.length; i++){
  blah[i].Foo = blah[i].foo;
  delete blah[i].foo;
  blah[i].Bar = blah[i].bar;
  delete blah[i].bar;
}
```

this approach allows you not to instantiate new objects. If your objects are complex and interconnected, this might be a preferred way